# How to turn off rendering only inside trigger volume in Unreal Engine 5.1

Tags: rendering, unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint, unreal-engine5, blueprint

my question is how can I turn off the rendering only inside a trigger volume on UE5.1. I want to make a slider section view of a building, and everything inside the trigger box must stay invisible. I think the trigger box should be capable of doing this with something as a mask or another thing, but actually I have no idea on how to make it. And if there's a way of doing this without the trigger box, I also want to know how. Thanks in advance for everyone who answer my question, I really need it!

I tried to make a mask that "cutoff" the materials but didn't work, any idea is welcome, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the SetActorHiddenInGame https://docs.unrealengine.com/5.1/en-US/BlueprintAPI/Rendering/SetActorHiddenInGame/ or the SetVisibility https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.27/en-US/BlueprintAPI/Rendering/SetVisibility/ function?

It's an immediate change that happens - so there are no fade-ins or fade-outs. Your trigger box idea is a good one.

You can get any actor entering the trigger box using the `OnActorBeginOverlap` event and then call the function `SetVisibility` of that actor and set the value `NewVisibility` as `False`.

Consequently, you get any actor leaving your trigger box using the `OnActorEndOverlap` event and call the `SetVisibility` of that actor with the value for `NewVisibility` as `True`.

That is a simple but effective way to make sure any actors that go inside your area will disappear.

Comment: Thak you for the answer! But the problem with SetVisibility is that the entire mesh disappear OnBeginOverlap, so if I have a volume wich goes only til the middle of the mesh, all the mesh will be gone, not just the part inside the trigger volume...

Comment: Ah, ok! Yeah - that's a whole mesh boolean solution, not something that will do that. 
The ideal way to move forward with that would be a dynamic material instance on all your actors or a post-process material on all actors against your volumes. Not super simple; I'll think about this and will edit my answer if I come up with a straightforward solution!

Answer (score 0):

If the trigger box intersects meshes the way I think you're suggesting, you'll struggle to tell the engine to globally exclude arbitrary parts of objects from the render.

You could instead try to actually cut parts of the meshes out using [Slice](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CYyceX21sfw). I don't know how complicated the scene is but the more complicated the scene the more complicated the setup is going to be to do this.